# Send new querystring params to action using mvc custom routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My requirement is to route a URL(eg: http://www.mywebsite.com/**helloworld**) to required controller(home) and action(index?type=1&mode=view) dynamically. Here I am saving incoming url, target controller + action + querystring params in database. For this I am using custom route handler which inherits MvcRouteHandler and in GetHttpHandler method of handler, i am updating route data values with controller name, action, params etc. These all works fine, but the problem is that I am not able to retrieve querystring params using Request.Querystring["type"], but possible to get values either as action params or from Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["type"]. Can anyone tell me that the changes we need to make to get values using Request.Querystring

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomUrlRoute",
            url: "{*CustomUrl}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "TestPortal.Controllers" },
            constraints: new { controller = @"^(?!services)\w+$" }
        ).RouteHandler = new CustomUrlRouteHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

Query string params are not part of a route, but the modelbinder will handle them the same as route params. In other words, if you want to capture those particular query string values in your action, just specify them as params to your action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int type, string mode)
```

Now, as far as automatically adding them to the URL, that's not really possible. Again, because the query string are not part of a route, you can't specify in a route that certain query string params should exist. However, you can set up a redirect. For example, you can have an action that responds to the `/helloworld` route, and then redirects to your desired URL:

```
public ActionResult HelloWorld()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { type = 1, mode = "view" });
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a URL rewrite directly in IIS to redirect from `/helloworld` to `/home/index?type=1&mode=view`. Just be advised that with either approach, the actual URL in the address bar will change to the one with the query string. The `/helloworld` route will just be a short URL, basically, to get people there easier, but will never actually be displayed in the address bar.

If you need to keep the `/helloworld` URL, then you will simply need to create a route for that, and handle the query string params as default values:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HelloWorld",
    url: "helloworld",
    defaults: new { controller: "Home", action: "Index" }
);
```

Then:

```
public ActionResult Index(int type = 1, string mode = "view")
```